# WPF XML Treeview - replace node name with inner text if name is 'value'

Tags: xml, wpf, treeview

I'm working on showing the xml file on WPF project

Following is xml contents

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<antecedents>
  <Panel>
    <antecedents>
      <a>
        <value>2075.000000 mm</value>
      </a>
      <b>
        <value>845.000000 mm</value>
      </b>
      <thick>
        <value>18.000000 mm</value>
      </thick>
      <mat>
        <value>315.000000 N/mm^2</value>
      </mat>
    </antecedents>
  </Panel>  
</antecedents>
```

I want to display this contents with treeview and <value> to be shown.

but my result is only showing only node names

like follow

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Khbcg.png)

I tried replace if the Name is 'value' then replace with InnerText

```
 <UserControl.Resources>
        <XmlDataProvider x:Key="xmlDataProvider" Source="Result.xml" XPath="*"/>

    </UserControl.Resources>

    <dxlc:LayoutControl>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="380"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="300"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <dxlc:LayoutGroup Grid.Row="0">
                <TreeView x:Name="xmlTreeView" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource xmlDataProvider}, XPath=*}">
                    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=*}">
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="5,0">
                                    **<TextBlock.Style>
                                        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                                            <Style.Triggers>
                                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Name}" Value="a">
                                                    <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding InnerText}"/>
                                                </DataTrigger>
                                            </Style.Triggers>
                                        </Style>
                                    </TextBlock.Style>**
                                </TextBlock>                                
                            </StackPanel>
                        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                </TreeView>
            </dxlc:LayoutGroup>
            <dxlc:LayoutGroup Grid.Row="1" Margin="0 0 10 0" Width="100" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                <dx:SimpleButton Width="100" Height="25"
                             HorizontalAlignment="Right"                             
                             Command="{Binding CloseDetailCommand}"
                             Content="Close"/>
            </dxlc:LayoutGroup>
        </Grid>
    </dxlc:LayoutControl>
```

What I expect is
[expect result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vahPc.png)

What do I have to do?